# Unit testing methods in Service Layer of Spring Boot Application

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito, microservices

I'm facing issues with Service Layer Test of a Spring Boot Application. Please consider that relevant imports and done and there are NO problems with gradle/pom dependencies.

Let's say I want to test **scheduleFreeze** method of class Sample

```
public class Sample{

    @Autowired
    private RDAO rDAO;

    @Autowired
    private RHelper rHelper;

    public void scheduleFreeze(){

    
    HashMap<String, HashSet<String>> myMap = rDAO.myMap(rHelper.getSortKey());
    //Some code to format map by making its values comma separated

    }

}
```

I'm writing a Service Layer test SampleTest. Here's the sample

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)
@Slf4j
public class SampleTest {

    @InjectMocks
    public Sample sample;

    @Mock
    private RDAO rDAO;

    @Mock
    private RHelper rHelper;

    private HashMap<String, HashSet<String>> testMap; // to be used for assertions

    private void uploadToDB(){
        //This fn creates table, creates dummy data and populates data to db tables
        //Also updates testMap
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp(){

     MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
     uploadToDB();

    }

    @Test
    public void scheduleFreezeTest() {
    
       sample.scheduleFreeze();

    }
}
```

I want the to cross verify/assert the contents of the **testMap** that I'm updating while populating to DB with the contents of **myMap** formed in scheduleFreeze function. How can I achieve this?

Edit - Ideally, I feel real methods of class Sample must be called to see the content in myMap

Comment: The `@SpringBootTest` annotation might be an overkill here if you _just_ want to write a unit test for your class as it populates the whole Spring Context for your test. If it was done by intention, make sure to understand the [difference between @Mock and @MockBean](https://rieckpil.de/difference-between-mock-and-mockbean-spring-boot-applications/).

Comment: When you say you want to populate data in your DB, why do you then plan to mock your DAO?